# Разница между document.querySelectorAll() и document.body.getElementByClassName()

Tags: javascript, dom

И `document.querySelectorAll("selector")` и `document.body.getElementsByClassName("selector")` возвращают массив найденных элементов по заданному селектору. Какая между ними разница тогда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например вот такая вот:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".div a") //  все ссылки в блоке с классом div
document.getElementsByClassName(".div a") // не найдет ничего
```

Суть в том, что `querySelectorAll` понимает валидные css-селекторы ( от сюда и название ), поэтому можете исхитряться, как только умеете

```
document.querySelectorAll("ul li:first") // первый li в списке
document.querySelectorAll("#id") // поиск по id
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=login]") // и такое умеет
```

**UPD**
В комментарии добавили, что тип возвращаемого массива отличается:

```
document.querySelectorAll() // NodeList
document.getElementsByClass() // HTMLCollection
```

Comment: А. То есть существуют такие методы, как getElementsByTagName(),  getElementsByClassName(),  getElementsById(). И все они для отдельных элементов. А querySelectorAll() может это все комбинировать?

Comment: @Orange_Dream, грубо говоря да + доп ф-ционал, за счет использования всей мощи `css-селекторов`, например, вложенность элементов и тд

Comment: Или вот такая :
Document.querySelectorAll() - возвращает объект типа NodeList.
Document.getElementsByClassName() -возвращает HTMLCollection дочерних элементов.Те можете получить элементы еще и по имени

Comment: Я разобрался. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, `querySelectorAll` принимает селектор, а `getElementsByClassName` - имя класса.

Во-вторых, `querySelectorAll` возвращает снимок - найденные элементы, а `getElementsByClassName` - живую коллекцию, осуществляя поиск при обращении к ней.

```js
var pre = document.querySelector("pre");
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".d"), b = document.getElementsByClassName("d");
pre.textContent += "Before: " + a.length + " and " + b.length + "\n";
document.querySelector(".u").classList.add("d");
pre.textContent += "After:  " + a.length + " and " + b.length + "\n";
```

```html
<div class=d></div>
<div class=d></div>
<div class=d></div>
<div class=d></div>
<div class=u></div>
<pre></pre>
```